# Angular 2/Typescript Delete Object On Button Click

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular2-directives

I have an `Angular 2` app using `Typescript` but i am new to this, what i have is a table with a 'Delete' button,

I can pass the object data to my confirmation modal but when i 'Confirm' it, its still in my table.

**delete-modal.component**

```
import { Component, OnInit, Inject, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { TestService } from '../../ABC/TestService/TestService.service';
import { MdDialog, MdDialogRef, MD_DIALOG_DATA } from '@angular/material';

import { testModal } from 'models/test';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-test',
    templateUrl: './test.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./test.css']
})

export class testDeleteModalComponent implements OnInit {
    @Input('test') test: testModal;

    constructor(private TestService: TestService, private accountService: AccountService,
        @Inject(MD_DIALOG_DATA) private dialogData: any) { }

    ngOnInit() {
        console.log('test', this.dialogData.beneficiary);
        this.test = this.dialogData.test;
    }

    deleteTest() {

        if (this.dialogData.test.identifier) {
            // this.dialogData.beneficiary.splice(this.dialogData.beneficiary.indexOf(this.beneficiaryAnt), 1);
            // this.dialogData.beneficiary.splice(this.beneficiary);
            // delete this.beneficiary;
            this.dialogData.test.splice(this.dialogData.test.indexOf(this.dialogData.test), 1);
        } else {
            this.dialogData.test.operation = 'X';
        }
    }
}
```

**HTML**

```
<button md-icon-button (click)="deleteTest()" name="deleteTestDetails">
    <md-icon>delete forever</md-icon>
</button>
```

All other `HTML` is in a main `component` and the 'Delete' button is used as shown below

```
<app-test-main-page-delete-button [test]="test"></app-test-main-page-delete-button>
```

The 'deleteTest' method is called when the user click the confirm button.

I have also included above some ways i have tried in the `IF` but they always come back

> ... is not a function

Comment: could you show how you implemented calling this function in html?

Comment: Use this.ref.detectChanges();
And import:
import { ChangeDetectorRef } from '@angular/core';
Documentation: https://angular.io/api/core/ChangeDetectorRef

Comment: can you share html codes ?

Comment: @SurenSrapyan `splice` or `indexof` as per my commented out code

Comment: @JaroslawK HTML added

Comment: @Chandru - Updated post

Comment: @Amit - Tried you solution but it's still displayed

Comment: @Murday1983, Please use it end of the DeleteTest() method, it should work

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is good that you asked this question, my projects of three peoples also struggling with this. we have found is two ways. what i will show is two ways of doing typescriptdelete.

solution a.
because it is object, it will need identifier. First is

```
var objectdelete = {
    identifier: 'Mydelte',
    value: '168%'
}
```

Next what we need is now service. some people call them directives but from my experience they are the same thing. We have alert so user knows if they did not set identifier that they must go back. I do not see service on your side, i see array being deleted. if you combine the array and the service, this will then be working across whole website.

```
export class DeleteService

delete(objectToDelete: string) {

    if (!objectToDelete.identifier) {
       alert('No identifer');
    }else {
        // Delete from your array here.
    }
}
```

Solution 2.

If the above does not meed your needs, our tema also experimented with interfaces in typescript. You can see them here https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html

so it becomes

```
export class myDeleteService {
    deleter: IDeleter
}

export interface IDeleter {
    delete: this.delete.delete(deletE);
    deleteArray: this.array =[];
}
```

then simply in your html it will be

```
<button (click)='delete(dieleter)'>Delete me!</button>
```

These are all common typescript behaviours for angular2/4/5 so we are hoping to become more used to them when we have hads more time to use them!

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to delete data object on button click and refresh instantly when it's done :

Your parent html has to call children like this :

```
<app-component [inputData]="dataTable" (inputDataChange)="resetData()"/>
```

Add dataTable as class variable and implement the output function :

```
resetData() { this.dataTable=[] }
```

Then in children html leave your code (you can use this changes)

```
<button class="fa fa-delete" (click)="deleteTest()" name="deleteTestDetails">Delete</button>
```

Finaly in your children ts file set your data object for each change, and implement your input function

```
myDataTable: any = [];
@Input set inputData(data: DataTable) {
   if(data) {
     this.myDataTable = data;
}}

@Output() inputDataChange: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();

deleteTest() {
   this.inputDataChange.emit(true); 
}
```

What does this code do ?
It will emit and event to the parent when the delete button is clicked, then your parent will delete the dataTable, and finally, your children input will refresh it, as setter will catch the changes and refresh the variable.

If you want to apply those rules to table changes, then simply emit your dataTable and reassign it instead of reset it.

Answer (score -1):

I am in a project with and our team have struggled on this for a whiles.

First thing I will say is this, Angular has not made this an easy task, so we will attempt to ignore the framework and write pure Java instead to make our lives easyer on ourselves.

SO looking at your button, I can see that you have started on the right track.

If the button is calling your component like the following

**Html/Java**

```
<button ng-click="delete()">Click me<button>
```

**Component.ts**

```
function delete = deleteMethod(testIdentifier) {
    var abc = this.beneficiary.beneficiaryIdentifier.test.splice(this.beneficiary.beneficiaryIdentifier.test.indexOf(testIdentifier));
    component2.deleteFunction();
}
```

**Component2.ts**

Then we can pass our identifiers into our parent or child components and remove the beneficiary like so:

```
deleteMethod(deetle) {
    this.beneficiary.removeAtIndex(testIdentifier.splice(1), 1);
}
```

Nice and easy looking back, but it took our team of threes a long whiles to figure that ones out.